# NoReverseMatch at /blog/ Django1.9 URL

Tags: python, django

can't figure out why the error NoReverseMatch,
trying to display links on the page Home.html

**Views:**

```
def show_article(request, article_id):
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, id=article_id)
    return render(request, 'blog/article.html', {'article': article})
```

**Url:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name="home"),
    url(r'^about/$', views.about, name='about'),
    url(r'^contact/$', views.contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^article/(?P<article_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.show_article, name='article'),
]
```

**Home.html:**

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block contaner %}
<div class="NameT">Главная</div>
<p>
  {% for article in articles %}
    <h4><a href="{% url 'article' article_id %}">{{ article.title }}</a></h4>
    <div><pre>{{ article.get_short_text }}</pre></div>
  {% endfor %}
</p>
{% endblock %}
```

**article.html:**

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block contaner %}
  <h1>{{ article.title }}</h1>
  <pre>{{ article.text }}</pre>
{% endblock %}
```

**Exception:**

```
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch

Exception Value:    

Reverse for 'article' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/article/(?P<article_id>[0-9]+)/$']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<h4><a href="{% url 'article' article_id %}">{{ article.title }}</a></h4>` is wrong, it should be:

`<h4><a href="{% url 'article' article.id %}">{{ article.title }}</a></h4>`

You were passing `article_id` as an argument, but the variable doesn't exist. But `article.id` is the id of an article and it is a valid value and most likely what you need.